# How to catch and handle failed mutation in Relay?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I have a Relay mutation which creates a post and prepends it to a post list.  The optimistic update will prepend the post's title and url to the list before the mutation gets sent out to my GraphQL server.  My problem is that when the mutation fails or is unable to complete, that optimistic update is removed from the list automatically after.  Is there a way to catch and handle a failed mutation so I could show some sort of message to the user indicating that the post cannot be saved?

My Relay mutation:

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

class CreatePostMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
    getMutation () {
        return Relay.QL`
            mutation {
                createPost
            }
        `
    }

    getVariables() {
        return {
            title: this.props.title,
            url: this.props.url
        }
    }

    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on CreatePostPayload {
                postEdge,
                store {
                    id
                }
            }
        `;
    }

    getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type: 'RANGE_ADD',
            parentName: 'store',
            parentID: this.props.store.id,
            connectionName: 'allPosts',
            edgeName: 'postEdge',
            rangeBehaviors: {
                '': 'prepend'
            }
        }]
    }

    getOptimisticResponse() {
        return {
            postEdge: {
                node: {
                    title: this.props.title,
                    url: this.props.url
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

export default CreatePostMutation;
```

My PostForm React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';

import CreatePostMutation from '../../mutations/create_post';

class PostForm extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let {relay, store} = this.props;
        let {title, url}   = this.refs;

        relay.commitUpdate(
            new CreatePostMutation({
                title: title.value,
                url: url.value,
                store
            })
        );

        // clear values
        title.value = '';
        url.value   = '';
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input name="title" placeholder="Title" ref="title" />
                    <input name="url" placeholder="URL" ref="url" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `PostForm` component's `handleSubmit` function, provide a callback to handle mutation failure while calling `commitUpdate`:

```
const onFailure = (transaction) => {
    // Notify user that the post could not be added.
};
const onSuccess = () => {
    console.log('Post added.')
};
relay.commitUpdate(
    new CreatePostMutation({
        title: title.value,
        url: url.value,
        store
    }),
    {onFailure, onSuccess}
);
```

You can find an example in [Relay mutation API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-store.html#commitupdate-static-method-example).

Note that, if you use the above approach, you'll receive system errors (e.g., exceptions thrown). You can also receive only one user error (e.g., validation error), if you throw error for problems with user input. If you want to receive all the user errors together, you may consider following an approach suggested in this excellent article: [Validation and User Errors in GraphQL Mutations](https://medium.com/@tarkus/validation-and-user-errors-in-graphql-mutations-39ca79cd00bf).